# diff command output not displaying properly

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am executing `diff` command for the below two files and output is not being displayed in a clear way.  Below are the files and requirement.

I have used `sort` for the files as it is beneficial with files with larger content in order to get accurate differences.  Without using `sort` for files with larger content, few values which are present in both the files are being displayed as differences, hence using `sort` in `diff` fixed it.

However I want output in a more formatted way as demonstrated below.

**file1.txt**

```
[head]
a=1
b=2
c=3

[tail]
d=0
e=2
```

**file2.txt**

```
[head]
a=1
b=2
c=4

[tail]
d=2
e=2

[HT]
a=24
```

Command used:

```
diff <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt) | grep '>' | sed 's/> *//'
```

**diff output:**

```
a=24
c=2
d=4
[HT]
```

**Need to achieve:**

```
[HT]
a=24
[head]
c=4
[tail]
d=2
```

---

**Executed the code provided by Nic3500:**

I almost got the expected output but when comparing configuration files,Iam getting section mysqld] multiple times like the below and files which have `.` are not being displayed properly and [mysqld] needs to be displayed only once instead of multiple times.

**ex:**

```
[mysqld]
max_connections=200
max_user_connections=300
    
[mysqld]
slow_query_log
query_cache_size=0
    
[mysqld]
ignore_db_dir
    
[mysqld].slow_query_log_file='/home/slow_query
log
```

Above the . after slow_query.log is being printed after [mysqld] and can that be printed like

```
slow_query_log_file='/home/slow_query.log'
```

Same thing for below:

```
[mysqld].log-error='/home/mysqld
log
```

Needs to be displayed as log-error='/home/mysqld.log'

Comment: If you want to keep sections, you will need to split into multiple files and call sort, etc multiple times

Comment: @stark Can you help me resolve this?

Comment: It's inaccurate to say the output isn't "proper". Until you introduce `grep` and `sed`, the output is exactly what `diff` is designed and documented to do. That you want something different does not make sort wrong; rather, it means you need a different, more specialized tool, instead of using generic text-analysis tools to process structured data.

Comment: One kind of pre-processing you could do, by the way, would be to put the section headers into the lines themselves. If your files contained things like `HT.a=24`, `head.c=4`, `tail.d=2`, it would be much easier to do the kind of processing you're looking for with simple line-oriented tools (like `comm`, `join`, etc).

Comment: Can we assume that the order of the variables is the same from file1 to file2?  Ex. in file1, you have a, b, c.  Is it always a, b, c in file2 as well?  If the order of lines is the same, it makes it much simpler than a generic ordering of variables.

Comment: @Nic3500 There would be some differences in the files,ex:There may be a,b,c in file 1 and in file 2 there might be a,b.

Comment: Must a solution use unix commands, or bash or is anything ok (ex python)?

Comment: @Nic3500 Unix or Bash only as I need to to merge this in shell script.

Comment: @Nic3500 I almost got the output with your code but need some changes as when comparing configuration files section is displaying multiple times and dot(.) is not being displaying properly,Can you please go through the question.

Comment: There's no reason you can't use Python in a shell script.

Comment: If it has to do with my answer, you should comment below said answer.  As for your problem, I tested my code with the files you provided.  I cannot modify the code to match some file I have never seen, please provide the files.  Or better yet, debug the code and learn in the process :)

Comment: FYI I edited the answer to fix the problem with `.`.  It will no longer cut the `.log` from your configurations.  It also fixed the problem with variables that do not have a value (ex. ignore_db_dir) in your question.  The code is only as valid as the test data provided...  **Please** view your question after edits, the formatting is all wrong.

Comment: @Nic3500 I tried to comment your answer first but the characters restriction couldn't make the content more clearer,So i edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got something working, it is not super elegant or full of bash wizardry, but it works.

**EDIT May 11th**: fixed the problem with the `.` in the values.  I had not tested with values containing `.` characters.  It also fixed problems when a variable does not have a value (i.e. no `=` sign in the line).

```
#!/bin/bash

# Takes a file in ini format and flattens it for easy diff
flatten_file ()
{
    file="$1"
    tmpfile="$2"

    section=""
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
        # empty lines are ignored
        if [[ "$line" =~ $^ ]]
        then
            continue
        else
            # Section lines are not written, but kept in a variable
            if [[ "$line" =~ \[.*\] ]]
            then
                section="$line"
            else
                # Other lines are written in the temp file
                echo "$section.$line" >>"$tmpfile"
            fi
        fi

    done < "$file"
}
################################################################################

# Check arguments
if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]
then
    echo "ERROR: must have 2 arguments, the files to compare." >&2
    exit 1
else
    file1="$1"
    if [[ ! -f "$file1" ]]
    then
        echo "ERROR: $file1 does not exist." >&2
        exit 2
    fi
    file2="$2"
    if [[ ! -f "$file2" ]]
    then
        echo "ERROR: $file2 does not exist." >&2
        exit 3
    fi
fi

# flatten file1
tmpfile1="/tmp/$$_file1.tmp"
>"$tmpfile1"
flatten_file "$file1" "$tmpfile1"
cat "$tmpfile1" >&2
echo "DEBUG ======================================" >&2

# flatten file2
tmpfile2="/tmp/$$_file2.tmp"
>"$tmpfile2"
flatten_file "$file2" "$tmpfile2"
cat "$tmpfile2" >&2
echo "DEBUG ======================================" >&2

tmpdiffout="/tmp/$$_diffout.tmp"
diff "$tmpfile1" "$tmpfile2" | grep '>' | sed 's/> *//' >"$tmpdiffout"
cat "$tmpdiffout" >&2
echo "DEBUG ======================================" >&2

# Print the output of diff into the ini file format
sectionoutput=""
while IFS= read -r outputline
do
    # for every line, print the section IF that section has no been output to screen already
    extracted_section=$(echo "$outputline" | cut -d'.' -f1)
    if [[ "$extracted_section" != "$sectionoutput" ]]
    then
        echo "$extracted_section"
        sectionoutput="$extracted_section"
    fi
    # for every line, output the variable and value in that line
    echo "$outputline" | cut -d'.' -f2-

done < "$tmpdiffout"

# Cleanup
rm -f "$tmpfile1"
rm -f "$tmpfile2"
rm -f "$tmpdiffout"
```

- To run this script, do: `./script.bash file1 file2 2>/dev/null`
- To see debug messages, do: `./script.bash file1 file2`

---

Function `flatten_file()` transforms your file formats (looks like an ini file) into what @Charles Duffy proposed in the comments.

Your file1 becomes

```
[head].a=1
[head].b=2
[head].c=3
[tail].d=0
[tail].e=2
```

And similarly for file2.  Then the same diff as you used is run to get the diffs.

---

Finally the diff output is formatted back into the desired format.  The output is therefore:

```
[head]
c=4
[tail]
d=2
[HT]
a=24
```

Note that is conserves the order of sections, so [HT] is at the bottom.  I do not see why you would want it on top since that does not follow the diff output order.

---

FYI if you are comparing strictly ini files, check https://superuser.com/questions/28738/how-to-compare-two-or-more-ini-files.  That is why I was asking about other languages - tools.